# Why do we not just use Minified JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

I see this word alot "minified" and i never seem to pick a script (ie. from jQuery plugins) that is "minified" but i suppose i should. If i'm right Minified means to remove all unecessary stuff from source code without changing its functionality, so why dont we just have minified source and why bother with the full blown version? Why give people the option?

YOLO

Comment: Note that the Microsoft AJAX library has both versions which automatically toggle depending on your `web.config`'s `<compilation debug="true/false">` setting.

Comment: Minified should really only be used for production environments, IMO.  Have you ever tried debugging jQuery + IE issues with minified source code?  It's NOT fun.  Line 1, column 12387?  No thanks...

Comment: why did someone vote this down? Arent you supposed to comment on why you vote something down...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When you're debugging, it's a lot easier to have the full source code. It's pretty difficult to debug when it says everything is on line 1 (since everything is usually condensed to just one long line), and an unreadable line 1 for that matter.

I test using the full blown version, and then I minify everything for deployment.

Comment: Not only is it in one line, but variable names are often changed to single letters, so it's hard to guess what each variable does.

Comment: *"I test using the full blown version, and then I minify everything for deployment."* ... and then test again, I presume?

Comment: munchybunch is correct. Testing and development (+debugging!) using the "full" versions, for all and possibly other reasons than listed above. When moving to production, use the "minified" version, or your own method of shrinking for bandwidth/other reasons.

Comment: @Tim: Develop with full version, stage/QA with min version, then deploy.  :)

Answer (score 9):

the minified version is difficult to understand and debug

Answer (score 4):

the answer is pretty simple and don't need further explanation IMHO, from the [jquery](http://jquery.com/) site

- CHOOSE YOUR COMPRESSION LEVEL:
- JQUERY-1.4.4.MIN.JS **PRODUCTION** (26KB, Minified and Gzipped)
- JQUERY-1.4.4.JS **DEVELOPMENT** (179KB, Uncompressed Code)

now, is fairly self explanatory:

- **PRODUCTION** = plug & play;
- **DEVELOPMENT** = Debugging, Modding, Coding....

hope this help!

Answer (score 3):

Oh no! There is a bug in jQuery. You have to find and repair it.

---

### You have used the minified version of jQuery.

This is the error message you have, your only tip on what could have happened:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )                       page.html:1
```

You do what you always do, looking at the line the error occured.

```
1      e)||n,m=i[n]||[],h=h[2]&&new RegExp("(^|\\.)"+o.join("\\.(?:.*\\.|)")+"(\\.|$)"),g=f=m.length;while(f--)k=m[f],!e&&p!==k.origType||c&&c.guid!==k.guid||h&&!h.test(k.namespace)||d&&d!==k.selector&&("**"!==d||!k.selector)||(m.splice(f,1),k.selector&&m.delegateCount--,l.remove&&l.remove.call(a,k));g&&!m.length&&(l.teardown&&l.teardown.call(a,o,q.handle)!==!1||r.removeEvent(a,n,q.handle),delete i[n])}else for(n in i)r.event.remove(a,n+b[j],c,d,!0);r.isEmptyObject(i)&&W.remove(a,"handle events")}},dispatch:function(a){var b=r.event.fix(a),c,d,e,f,g,h,i=new Array(arguments.length),j=(W.get(this,"events")||{})[b.type]||[],k=r.event.special[b.type]||{};for(i[0]=b,c=1;c<arguments.length;c++)i[c]=arguments[c];if(b.delegateTarget=this,!k.preDispatch||k.preDispatch.call(this,b)!==!1){h=r.event.handlers.call(this,b,j),c=0;while((f=h[c++])&&!b.isPropagationStopped()){b.currentTarget=f.elem,d=0;while((g=f.handlers[d++])&&!b.isImmediatePropagationStopped())b.rnamespace&&!b.rnamespace.test(g.namespace)||(b.handleObj=g,b.data=g.data,e=((r.event.special[g.origType]||{}).handle||g.handler).apply(f.elem,i),void 0!==e&&(b.result=e)===!1&&(b.preventDefault(),b.stopPropagation()))}return k.postDispatch&&k.postDispatch.call(this,b),b.result}},handlers:function(a,b){var c,d,e,f,g,h=[],i=b.delegateCount,j=a.target;if(i&&j.nodeType&&!("click"===a.type&&a.button>=1))for(;j!==this;j=j.parentNode||this)if(1===j.nodeType&&("click"!==a.type||j.disabled!==!0)){for(f=[],g={},c=0;c<i;c++)d=b[c],e=d.selector+" ",void 0===g[e]&&(g[e]=d.needsContext?r(e,this).index(j)>-1:r.find(e,this,null,[j]).length),g[e]&&f.push(d);f.length&&h.push({elem:j,handlers:f})}return j=this,i<b.length&&h.push({elem:j,handlers:b.slice(i)}),h},addProp:function(a,b){Object.defineProperty(r.Event.prototype,a,{enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,get:r.isFunction(b)?function(){if(this.originalEvent)return b(this.originalEvent)}:function(){if(this.originalEvent)return this.originalEvent[a]},set:function(b){Object.defineProperty(this,a,{enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,writable:!0,value:b})}})},fix:function(a){return a[r.expando]?a:new r.Event(a)},special:{load:{noBubble:!0},focus:{trigger:function(){if(this!==xa()&&this.focus)return this.focus(),!1},delegateType:"focusin"},blur:{trigger:function(){if(this===xa()&&this.blur)return this.blur(),!1},delegateType:"focusout"},click:{trigger:function(){if("checkbox"===this.type&&this.click&&B(this,"input"))return this.click(),!1},_default:function(a){return B(a.target,"a")}},beforeunload:{postDispatch:function(a){void 0!==a.result&&a.originalEvent&&(a.originalEvent.returnValue=a.result)}}}},r.removeEvent=function(a,b,c){a.removeEventListener&&a.removeEventListener(b,c)},r.Event=function(a,b){return this instanceof r.Event?(a&&a.type?(this.originalEvent=a,this.type=a.type,this.isDefaultPrevented=a.defaultPrevented||void 0===a.defaultPrevented&&a.returnValue===!1?va:wa,this.target=a.target&&3===a.target.nodeType?a.target.parentNode:a.target,this.currentTarget=a.currentTarget,this.relatedTarget=a.relatedTarget):this.type=a,b&&r.extend(this,b),this.timeStamp=a&&a.timeStamp||r.now(),void(this[r.expando]=!0)):new r.Event(a,b)},r.Event.prototype={constructor:r.Event,isDefaultPrevented:wa,isPropagationStopped:wa,isImmediatePropagationStopped:wa,isSimulated:!1,preventDefault:function(){var a=this.originalEvent;this.isDefaultPrevented=va,a&&!this.isSimulated&&a.preventDefault()},stopPropagation:function(){var a=this.originalEvent;this.isPropagationStopped=va,a&&!this.isSimulated&&a.stopPropagation()},stopImmediatePropagation:function(){var a=this.originalEvent;this.isImmediatePropagationStopped=va,a&&!this.isSimulated&&a.stopImmediatePropagation(),this.stopPropagation()}},r.each({altKey:!0,bubbles:!0,cancelable:!0,changedTouches:!0,ctrlKey:!0,detail:!0,eventPhase:!0,metaKey:!0,pageX:!0,pageY:!0,shiftKey:!0,view:!0,"char":!0,charCode:!0,key:!0,keyCode:!0,button:!0,buttons:!0,clientX:!0,clientY:!0,offsetX:!0,offsetY:!0,pointerId:!0,pointerType:!0,screenX:!0,screenY:!0,targetTouches:!0,toElement:!0,touches:!0,which:function(a){var b=a.button;return null==a.which&&sa.test(a.type)?null!=a.charCode?a.charCode:a.keyCode:!a.which&&void 0!==b&&ta.test(a.type)?1&b?1:2&b?3:4&b?2:0:a.which}},r.event.addProp),r.each({mouseenter:"mouseover",mouseleave:"mouseout",pointerenter:"pointerover",pointerleave:"pointerout"},function(a,b){r.event.special[a]={delegateType:b,bindType:b,handle:function(a){var c,d=this,e=a.relatedTarget,f=a.handleObj;return e&&(e===d||r.contains(d,e))||(a.type=f.origType,c=f.handler.apply(this,arguments),a.type=b),c}}}),r.fn.extend({on:function(a,b,c,d){return ya(this,a,b,c,d)},one:function(a,b,c,d){return ya(this,a,b,c,d,1)},off:function(a,b,c){var d,e;if(a&&a.preventDefault&&a.handleObj)return d=a.handleObj,r(a.delegateTarget).off(d.namespace?d.origType+"."+d.namespace:d.origType,d.selector,d.handler),this;if("object"==typeof a){for(e in a)this.off(e,b,a[e]);return this}return b!==!1&&"function"!=typeof b||(c=b,b=void 0),c===!1&&(c=wa),this.each(function(){r.event.remove(this,a,c,b)})}});var za=/<(?!area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)(([a-z][^\/\0>\x20\t\r\n\f]*)[^>]*)\/>/gi,Aa=/<script|<style|<link/i,Ba=/checked\s*(?:[^=]|=\s*.checked.)/i,Ca=/^true\/(.*)/,Da=/^\s*<!(?:\[CDATA\[|--)|(?:\]\]|--)>\s*$/g;function Ea(a,b){return B(a,"table")&&B(11!==b.nodeType?b:b.firstChild,"tr")?r(">tbody",a)[0]||a:a}function Fa(a){return a.type=(null!==a.getAttribute("type"))+"/"+a.type,a}function Ga(a){var b=Ca.exec(a.type);return b?a.type=b[1]:a.removeAttribute("type"),a}function Ha(a,b){var c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j;if(1===b.nodeType){if(W.hasData(a)&&(f=W.access(a),g=W.set(b,f),j=f.events)){delete g.handle,g.events={};for(e in j)for(c=0,d=j[e].length;c<d;c++)r.event.add(b,e,j[e][c])}X.hasData(a)&&(h=X.access(a),i=r.extend({},h),X.set(b,i))}}function Ia(a,b){var c=b.nodeName.toLowerCase();"input"===c&&ja.test(a.type)?b.checked=a.checked:"input"!==c&&"textarea"!==c||(b.defaultValue=a.defaultValue)}function Ja(a,b,c,d){b=g.apply([],b);var e,f,h,i,j,k,l=0,m=a.length,n=m-1,q=b[0],s=r.isFunction(q);if(s||m>1&&"string"==typeof q&&!o.checkClone&&Ba.test(q))return a.each(function(e){var f=a.eq(e);s&&(b[0]=q.call(this,e,f.html())),Ja(f,b,c,d)});if(m&&(e=qa(b,a[0].ownerDocument,!1,a,d),f=e.firstChild,1===e.childNodes.length&&(e=f),f||d)){for(h=r.map(na(e,"script"),Fa),i=h.length;l<m;l++)j=e,l!==n&&(j=r.clone(j,!0,!0),i&&r.merge(h,na(j,"script"))),c.call(a[l],j,l);if(i)for(k=h[h.length-1].ownerDocument,r.map(h,Ga),l=0;l<i;l++)j=h[l],la.test(j.type||"")&&!W.access(j,"globalEval")&&r.contains(k,j)&&(j.src?r._evalUrl&&r._evalUrl(j.src):p(j.textContent.replace(Da,""),k))}return a}function Ka(a,b,c){for(var d,e=b?r.filter(b,a):a,f=0;null!=(d=e[f]);f++)c||1!==d.nodeType||r.cleanData(na(d)),d.parentNode&&(c&&r.contains(d.ownerDocument,d)&&oa(na(d,"script")),d.parentNode.removeChild(d));return a}r.extend({htmlPrefilter:function(a){return a.replace(za,"<$1></$2>")},clone:function(a,b,c){var d,e,f,g,h=a.cloneNode(!0),i=r.contains(a.ownerDocument,a);if(!(o.noCloneChecked||1!==a.nodeType&&11!==a.nodeType||r.isXMLDoc(a)))for(g=na(h),f=na(a),d=0,e=f.length;d<e;d++)Ia(f[d],g[d]);if(b)if(c)for(f=f||na(a),g=g||na(h),d=0,e=f.length;d<e;d++)Ha(f[d],g[d]);else Ha(a,h);return g=na(h,"script"),g.length>0&&oa(g,!i&&na(a,"script")),h},cleanData:function(a){for(var b,c,d,e=r.event.special,f=0;void 0!==(c=a[f]);f++)if(U(c)){if(b=c[W.expando]){if(b.events)for(d in b.events)e[d]?r.event.remove(c,d):r.removeEvent(c,d,b.handle);c[W.expando]=void 0}c[X.expando]&&(c[X.expando]=void 0)}}}),r.fn.extend({detach:function(a){return Ka(this,a,!0)},remove:function(a){return Ka(this,a)},text:function(a){return T(this,function(a){return void 0===a?r.text(this):this.empty().each(function(){1!==this.nodeType&&11!==this.nodeType&&9!==this.nodeType||(this.textContent=a)})},null,a,arguments.length)},append:function(){return Ja(this,arguments,function(a){if(1===this.nodeType||11===this.nodeType||9===this.nodeType){var b=Ea(this,a);b.appendChild(a)}})},prepend:function(){return Ja(this,arguments,function(a){if(1===this.nodeType||11===this.nodeType||9===this.nodeType){var b=Ea(this,a);b.insertBefore(a,b.firstChild)}})},before:function(){return Ja(this,arguments,function(a){this.parentNode&&this.parentNode.insertBefore(a,this)})},after:function(){return Ja(this,arguments,function(a){this.parentNode&&this.parentNode.insertBefore(a,this.nextSibling)})},empty:function(){for(var a,b=0;null!=(a=this[b]);b++)1===a.nodeType&&(r.cleanData(na(a,!1)),a.textContent="");return this},clone:function(a,b){return a=null!=a&&a,b=null==b?a:b,this.map(function(){return r.clone(this,a,b)})},html:function(a){return T(this,function(a){var b=this[0]||{},c=0,d=this.length;if(void 0===a&&1===b.nodeType)return b.innerHTML;if("string"==typeof a&&!Aa.test(a)&&!ma[(ka.exec(a)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()]){a=r.htmlPrefilter(a);try{for(;c<d;c++)b=this[c]||{},1===b.nodeType&&(r.cleanData(na(b,!1)),b.innerHTML=a);b=0}catch(e){}}b&&this.empty().append(a)},null,a,arguments.length)},replaceWith:function(){var a=[];return Ja(this,arguments,function(b){var c=this.parentNode;r.inArray(this,a)<0&&(r.cleanData(na(this)),c&&c.replaceChild(b,this))},a)}}),r.each({appendTo:"append",prependTo:"prepend",insertBefore:"before",insertAfter:"after",replaceAll:"replaceWith"},function(a,b){r.fn[a]=function(a){for(var c,d=[],e=r(a),f=e.length-1,g=0;g<=f;g++)c=g===f?this:this.clone(!0),r(e[g])[b](c),h.apply(d,c.get());return this.pushStack(d)}});var La=/^margin/,Ma=new RegExp("^("+aa+")(?!px)[a-z%]+$","i"),Na=function(b){var c=b.ownerDocument.defaultView;return c&&c.opener||(c=a),c.getComputedStyle(b)};!function(){function b(){if(i){i.style.cssText="box-sizing:border-box;position:relative;display:block;margin:auto;border:1px;padding:1px;top:1%;width:50%",i.innerHTML="",ra.appendChild(h);var b=a.getComputedStyle(i);c="1%"!==b.top,g="2px"===b.marginLeft,e="4px"===b.width,i.style.marginRight="50%",f="4px"===b.marginRight,ra.removeChild(h),i=null}}var c,e,f,g,h=d.createElement("div"),i=d.createElement("div");i.style&&(i.style.backgroundClip="content-box",i.cloneNode(!0).style.backgroundClip="",o.clearCloneStyle="content-box"===i.style.backgroundClip,h.style.cssText="border:0;width:8px;height:0;top:0;left:-9999px;padding:0;margin-top:1px;position:absolute",h.appendChild(i),r.extend(o,{pixelPosition:function(){return b(),c},boxSizingReliable:function(){return b(),e},pixelMarginRight:function(){return b(),f},reliableMarginLeft:function(){return b(),g}}))}();function Oa(a,b,c){var d,e,f,g,h=a.style;return c=c||Na(a),c&&(g=c.getPropertyValue(b)||c[b],""!==g||r.contains(a.ownerDocument,a)||(g=r.style(a,b)),!o.pixelMarginRight()&&Ma.test(g)&&La.test(b)&&(d=h.width,e=h.minWidth,f=h.maxWidth,h.minWidth=h.maxWidth=h.width=g,g=c.width,h.width=d,h.minWidth=e,h.maxWidth=f)),void 0!==g?g+"":g}function Pa(a,b){return{get:function(){return a()?void delete this.get:(this.get=b).apply(this,arguments)}}}var Qa=/^(none|table(?!-c[ea]).+)/,Ra=/^--/,Sa={position:"absolute",visibility:"hidden",display:"block"},Ta={letterSpacing:"0",fontWeight:"400"},Ua=["Webkit","Moz","ms"],Va=d.createElement("div").style;function Wa(a){if(a in Va)return a;var b=a[0].toUpperCase()+a.slice(1),c=Ua.length;while(c--)if(a=Ua[c]+b,a in Va)return a}function Xa(a){var b=r.cssProps[a];return b||(b=r.cssProps[a]=Wa(a)||a),b}function Ya(a,b,c){var d=ba.exec(b);return d?Math.max(0,d[2]-(c||0))+(d[3]||"px"):b}function Za(a,b,c,d,e){var f,g=0;for(f=c===(d?"border":"content")?4:"width"===b?1:0;f<4;f+=2)"margin"===c&&(g+=r.css(a,c+ca[f],!0,e)),d?("content"===c&&(g-=r.css(a,"padding"+ca[f],!0,e)),"margin"!==c&&(g-=r.css(a,"border"+ca[f]+"Width",!0,e))):(g+=r.css(a,"padding"+ca[f],!0,e),"padding"!==c&&(g+=r.css(a,"border"+ca[f]+"Width",!0,e)));return g}function $a(a,b,c){var d,e=Na(a),f=Oa(a,b,e),g="border-box"===r.css(a,"boxSizing",!1,e);return Ma.test(f)?f:(d=g&&(o.boxSizingReliable()||f===a.style[b]),"auto"===f&&(f=a["offset"+b[0].toUpperCase()+b.slice(1)]),f=parseFloat(f)||0,f+Za(a,b,c||(g?"border":"content"),d,e)+"px")}r.extend({cssHooks:{opacity:{get:function(a,b){if(b){var c=Oa(a,"opacity");return""===c?"1":c}}}},cssNumber:{animationIterationCount:!0,columnCount:!0,fillOpacity:!0,flexGrow:!0,flexShrink:!0,fontWeight:!0,lineHeight:!0,opacity:!0,order:!0,orphans:!0,widows:!0,zIndex:!0,zoom:!0},cssProps:{"float":"cssFloat"},style:function(a,b,c,d){if(a&&3!==a.nodeType&&8!==a.nodeType&&a.style){var e,f,g,h=r.camelCase(b),i=Ra.test(b),j=a.style;return i||(b=Xa(h)),g=r.cssHooks[b]||r.cssHooks[h],void 0===c?g&&"get"in g&&void 0!==(e=g.get(a,!1,d))?e:j[b]:(f=typeof c,"string"===f&&(e=ba.exec(c))&&e[1]&&(c=fa(a,b,e),f="number"),null!=c&&c===c&&("number"===f&&(c+=e&&e[3]||(r.cssNumber[h]?"":"px")),o.clearCloneStyle||""!==c||0!==b.indexOf("background")||(j[b]="inherit"),g&&"set"in g&&void 0===(c=g.set(a,c,d))||(i?j.setProperty(b,c):j[b]=c)),void 0)}},css:function(a,b,c,d){var e,f,g,h=r.camelCase(b),i=Ra.test(b);return i||(b=Xa(h)),g=r.cssHooks[b]||r.cssHooks[h],g&&"get"in g&&(e=g.get(a,!0,c)),void 0===e&&(e=Oa(a,b,d)),"normal"===e&&b in Ta&&(e=Ta[b]),""===c||c?(f=parseFloat(e),c===!0||isFinite(f)?f||0:e):e}}),r.each(["height","width"],function(a,b){r.cssHooks[b]={get:function(a,c,d){if(c)return!Qa.test(r.css(a,"display"))||a.getClientRects().length&&a.getBoundingClientRect().width?$a(a,b,d):ea(a,Sa,function(){return $a(a,b,d)})},set:function(a,c,d){var e,f=d&&Na(a),g=d&&Za(a,b,d,"border-box"===r.css(a,"boxSizing",!1,f),f);return g&&(e=ba.exec(c))&&"px"!==(e[3]||"px")&&(a.style[b]=c,c=r.css(a,b)),Ya(a,c,g)}}}),r.cssHooks.marginLeft=Pa(o.reliableMarginLeft,function(a,b){if(b)return(parseFloat(Oa(a,"marginLeft"))||a.getBoundingClientRect().left-ea(a,{marginLeft:0},function(){return a.getBoundingClientRect().left}))+"px"}),r.each({margin:"",padding:"",border:"Width"},function(a,b){r.cssHooks[a+b]={expand:function(c){for(var d=0,e={},f="string"==typeof c?c.split(" "):[c];d<4;d++)e[a+ca[d]+b]=f[d]||f[d-2]||f[0];return e}},La.test(a)||(r.cssHooks[a+b].set=Ya)}),r.fn.extend({css:function(a,b){return T(this,function(a,b,c){var d,e,f={},g=0;if(Array.isArray(b)){for(d=Na(a),e=b.length;g<e;g++)f[b[g]]=r.css(a,b[g],!1,d);return f}return void 0!==c?r.style(a,b,c):r.css(a,b)},a,b,arguments.length>1)}});function _a(a,b,c,d,e){return new _a.prototype.init(a,b,c,d,e)}r.Tween=_a,_a.prototype={constructor:_a,init:function(a,b,c,d,e,f){this.elem=a,this.prop=c,this.easing=e||r.easing._default,this.options=b,this.start=this.now=this.cur(),this.end=d,this.unit=f||(r.cssNumber[c]?"":"px")},cur:function(){var a=_a.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this):_a.propHooks._default.get(this)},run:function(a){var b,c=_a.propHooks[this.prop];return this.options.duration?this.pos=b=r.easing[this.easing](a,this.options.duration*a,0,1,this.options.duration):this.pos=b=a,this.now=(this.end-this.start)*b+this.start,this.options.step&&this.options.step.call(this.elem,this.now,this),c&&c.set?c.set(this):_a.propHooks._default.set(this),this}},_a.prototype.init.prototype=_a.prototype,_a.propHooks={_default:{get:function(a){var b;return 1!==a.elem.nodeType||null!=a.elem[a.prop]&&null==a.elem.style[a.prop]?a.elem[a.prop]:(b=r.css(a.elem,a.prop,""),b&&"auto"!==b?b:0)},set:function(a){r.fx.step[a.prop]?r.fx.step[a.prop](a):1!==a.elem.nodeType||null==a.elem.style[r.cssProps[a.prop]]&&!r.cssHooks[a.prop]?a.elem[a.prop]=a.now:r.style(a.elem,a.prop,a.now+a.unit)}}
```

Have fun!

---

### You have used the normal version of jQuery.

This is your error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )                       page.html:5994
```

You do what you always do, looking at the line the error occured.

```
5992    l = this.length;
5993
5994    if ( value === undefined && elem. ) {
5995        return elem.innerHTML;
5996    }
5997
5998    // See if we can take a shortcut and just use innerHTML
5999    if ( typeof value === "string" && !rnoInnerhtml.test( value ) && !wrapMap[ ( rtagName.exec( value ) || [ "", "" ] )[ 1 ].toLowerCase() ] ) {
```

Better, isn't it?

---

I know, late to the party, but I had so much fun making this :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand how the script works or extend it, then you better have a non-minified version of it.

Answer (score 1):

Minified script is difficult to read for a human, and it's difficult to debug. For Javascript libraries like jQuery, it's nice to be able to read the source of whatever function you're using during debugging, to better understand how it works. In a production environment, you should definitely go with the minified version to speed up the data transfer.

Comment: It should also speed up the parsing since there are less characters to process.  But it's probably insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, originally, whoever wrote the JavaScript libraries wrote them as the "full-version" i.e. with the comments and code formatting built in - because as mentioned, code is far easier to read this way. However, whoever wrote the JavaScript libraries also knows that the minified version will be more lightweight and web friendly. Since the developer already has the "full-version", why would he/she not provide it along with a minified version?

In this case, providing a "full-version" does not require any extra work because it IS the original version. As long as the developer is going to provide a minified version - he might as well provide the full version used to make the minified version. With an open source JS library, providing a full version with comments and code formatting just makes it all that easier for the community to figure out what's going on.

That said I would recommend using the minified version in your production environments. Preferably a minified version delivered over a [CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html).

Answer (score 0):

To be simple , minified version is for production and non minimfied version is for development debugging purposes.

Espicially for performance , minified version is better. You can check the differenence between the load times through firebug net panel

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use a PHP script to minify (and cache / gzip if needed) your js scripts on the fly. It's what I do most of the time.

It has all of the advantages of minifying your javascript without the disadvantages. 
Saves about 70% (gzip+minify) of the data transfered.